# Background image in div not working in Safari & Chrome, but works in Mozilla

Tags: css

I've three divs, by default two of which are hidden. On clicking a button, respective div will be visible.

I've three different background images for three divs & on clicking the button, I want background image to be changed, too. However that isn't working in Safari & Chrome, but works good in Mozilla.

**What is not working**

Background image stays the same in Safari & Chrome, changes in Mozilla.

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
.banner_1{
        width:100%;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed, fixed;
        background-position: center 100%, center 100%, center 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat, repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: cover, cover, cover;

}

.banner_2{
        width:100%;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner2.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner2.jpg");
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner2.jpg");
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner2.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed, fixed;
        background-position: center 100%, center 100%, center 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat, repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: cover, cover, cover;
    }

.banner_3{
        width:100%;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner3.jpg");
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner3.jpg");
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner3.jpg");
        background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(160,167,232,0.25), rgba(86,153,158,0.35)), linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), url("../../images/banner3.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed, fixed, fixed;
        background-position: center 100%, center 100%, center 100%;
        background-repeat: repeat, repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: cover, cover, cover;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<section class='index_banner banner_1 show'>
    <div class='middle'>
        Hey
    </div>
</section>
<section class='index_banner banner_2 hide'>
    <div class='middle'>
        Hey
    </div>
</section>
<section class='index_banner banner_3 hide'>
    <div class='middle'>
        Hey
    </div>
</section>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.one').click(function(){
            $('.banner_1').show();
            $('.banner_2').hide();
            $('.banner_3').hide();
        });
        $('.two').click(function(){
            $('.banner_1').hide();
            $('.banner_2').show();
            $('.banner_3').hide();
        });
    });
```

Can anybody tell why it isn't working in two browsers? And what can be done to have it working?

Comment: What is not working exactly? I've got [the same output](http://jsfiddle.net/mp34joz9/) on chrome, safari and FF. However, your code is not changing div's background image at all, but show or hide the whole divs.

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I'm doing & that shouldn't make the difference for any browser. However in Chrome & Safari, background image stays the same which is present while DOM loading.

Comment: Can't repro with the fiddle I linked.

Comment: You say by default, two divs are hidden. But in the fiddle, all three divs are visible initially, is that right?